# How to print FF (form feed) character?

Tags: python

I do some old report conversion and need to add "new page" FF character.
What's the syntax to print FF character from Python?

Comment: Why not just `print('\f')`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like [this *Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) says *Form Feed (FF)* has decimal value **12 in ASCII**. Which is `0x0c` in hex:

> Form feed is a page-breaking ASCII control character. It forces the
>   printer to eject the current page and to continue printing at the top
>   of another. Often, it will also cause a carriage return. The form feed
>   character code is defined as **12** (**0xC** in hexadecimal) (..) In the C programming language (and other languages derived from C), the **form feed character is represented as `'\f'`**.

So you can:

```
print('\x0c',end='')
```

Or you can use - like [@martineau says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955635/how-to-print-ff-form-feed-character-in-python/44955680#comment76886889_44955680) - use `'\f'`:

```
print('\f',end='')
```

The `end=''` is used to prevent Python from printing an additional new line after the form feed character.

Note that it depends on the console (or the device that receives the stream) how the Form Feed is handled. Some consoles might ignore it. Others print a few blank lines, and a printer might for instance decide to start a new page.

Comment: `'\f'` is easier to remember.