# How to read Ctrl command characters from a file in Python

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, ctrl

Right now I am trying to read and parse a file using Python 2. The creator of the file typed a bunch of lines in the terminal, with (Ctrl A)s within each line, and copied those lines into a text file. So the lines in the file look like "(something)^A(something)". When I use the readlines() function in python to read the file, those "^A" strings cannot be recognized.

I tried to use io.open and codecs.open and set the encoding as UTF-8, but "^A" is clearly not an UTF-8 string. Does anyone know how to read these special control command strings from a file using python? Thank you very much!

Comment: Generally speaking, on this site it is encouraged to post your code. Hard to advise where you are going wrong otherwise.

You need to open the file in binary read mode, read in the bytes and examine each byte so that it matches the ascii code for Ctrl-A (which I believe is the value 1).

Comment: Do you know how I am supposed to read by byte and match value 1 in python? Like using which function?

Comment: Control characters are invisible characters, so the terminal uses ^A as a visual representation. You don't want to actually look for ^A if there's a control character. But it's hard to tell what is actually stored in the file. I suggest using an editor which displays invisible characters in a special way to make sure. Then you can use various [escaping methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) to represent invisible characters and look for them.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be recognized"? Do you get an exception? If so, what is it and what does the code look like?

Comment: I mean the "^A" cannot be read and becomes invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply read the file in binary mode like so: `open('file.txt', 'rb')`. Ctrl-A will be the value 1.

```
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
    for char in text:
        if char == b'\x01': # \x01 stands for the byte with hex value 01
            # Do something
            pass
        else:
            # Do something else
            pass
```

Comment: I didn't use the exact same method, but you gave me some pretty good inspiration. Instead of using str.find("^A") in my program, I used str.find("\x01") and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These control characters are part of the [ASCII character set](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html), with numeric codes ranging from 0 to 31 (or 00 to 1F in hexadecimals). To strip them out from a string, simply use regex substitution:

```
import re
clean_string = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f]+', '', string_with_control_characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the link below I realized that **^L**, is the control character for form feed.
http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html

Then I found this answer from the following link:
[How to print FF (form feed) character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955635/how-to-print-ff-form-feed-character)

I executed the following code and it worked perfectly.

```
if '\f' in char:
```